# Under 18 years applying for B2 visa to USA

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I'm 17 and my brother is 14 we are both applying for a non immigrant visa to USA as we're going on holiday in the summer and were denied ESTA having travelled to Iran. I was wondering what questions we would be asked in the interview due to being under 18 as most questions I've seen are about how much you earn etc.
If anyone has any idea that would help, thanks

Comment: Minors  will have to go with your parents/legal guardians or you will be denied the visas. Minors are asked simple questions like who are you going to visit, where will you be going, and who is financing your trip, which school you attend and what grade you are in. They will have questions for your parents and those are what will carry the most weight in whether you get visas or not. 
`Applications for minors under the age of 16 should be submitted by the parent of the child. Both the child and the parent must appear in person. Additionally, the following are required:`

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie If you add the link, that looks like an answer!

Answer (score 3):

Minors will have to go with your parents/legal guardians or you will typically be denied the visas. Minors are asked simple questions like *who are you going to visit, where will you be going, and who is financing your trip, which school you attend and what grade you are in*. They will have questions for your parents and those are what will carry the most weight in whether you get visas or not.

I know this from experience with inviting my minor nephew to the USA some years ago.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer comes from a wrong source! This link is about passport service for minor us citizens. They were asking for a visa application minor tourists.